# ¿Como iterar valores entre corchetes?

Tags: php

Necesito iterar con PHP valores que traigo de mi Base de Datos y que estan entre corchetes `[158][547][1268]`, pense en un explode pero yo necesito el valor que esta dentro de los corchetes. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternativa sin regexp

- borramos primer `[`
- borramos último `]`
- reemplazamos `][` por `,`

---

```
<?php
$cadena = "[158][547][1268]"; 
$cadena = str_replace( '][', ',', rtrim( ltrim( $cadena, '['), ']' ) ); 

echo $cadena;
```

---

resultado:

```
158,547,1268
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$cadena = "[158][547][1268]"; 

//fuera []
$cadena = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $cadena); 
//fuera espacios
$cadena=trim($cadena);
echo $cadena;

 // explode con doble espacio and voila !!
$porciones = explode("  ", $cadena);
print_r($porciones);
```

Look this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: Gracias Cristian por tu respuesta, me sirvio mucho... una duda.... se puede hacer que los valores queden separados con coma? es decir asi 158,547,1268

Comment: Hola si revisa la documentacion de las funciones ya mencionadas y se un ninja de php saludos ! , mas abajo ya han comentado excelentes soluciones incluso mas breves , por tiempo no las he mejorado.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener los datos numericos a partir de la cadena `$cadena = "[158][547][1268]"` separados por espacio puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
<?php

$cadena = "[158][547][1268]"; 

$cadena = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/',' ', $cadena); 
$cadena=trim($cadena);
$cadena = str_replace('  ', ' ', $cadena);
print_r($cadena);
```

para obtener:

```
158 547 1268
```

---

Si deseas separarlos por coma lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
<?php

$cadena = "[158][547][1268]"; 

$cadena = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/',' ', $cadena); 
$cadena=trim($cadena);
$cadena = str_replace('  ', ',', $cadena);
print_r($cadena);
```

para obtener:

```
158,547,1268
```